# How can I re-use this navbar React component in files other than index.html?

Tags: html, reactjs

I was trying to build a simple website using React. I have to include a navigation bar which should appear in every page at the top. So i thought i can use react to reuse this nav bar in different HTML pages.But I am unable to do so. Is my approach wrong. I am very new to using React.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Nav.css';
import maitlogo from './maitlogo.png';
class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div id="parent">
        <div className="heading">   
    <img class="logo" src={maitlogo} alt="logo"/>
        <h1 className="title">Maharaja Agrasen Insitute of technology,Delhi</h1>
        </div>
        <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='index.html'><span>HOME</span></a></li>
               <li className='active'><a href='login.html'><span>LOGIN</span></a>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a href='login.html'><span>STUDENT</span></a></li>
                         <li><a href='login2.html'><span>TEACHER</span></a></li>
                         </ul>
               </li>
               <li><a href='a.html'><span>ABOUT US</span></a></li>
               <li className='last'><a href='contacts.html'><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Nav;
```

I have tried the above code in `index.html` and `login.html` but it is only working in `index.html`.

Comment: I'm a bit curious about how you config `login.html` to render react components? If you are new to react, you should try Single Page Application first. By default, react is only rerendering the index.html with id **root**. I guessed you are failed at this, because you don't provide more infos about this and just use `<a href ...>` and said *unable to do so* simply.

Comment: i provided my login.html code below

Comment: If the above **Javascript** code is your login.html, you need to check the react documentation or the tutorial first completely... The concept of React is not what you intended to do now. Sorry, I'm really surprised, no offense.

Comment: Not the above one sir.The code that i commented to the user who answered my question.You can find it below also                                              .<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>a</title>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse `React component` on different `html` pages, you have to create a placeholder `div` each page then `render` the component into that `div`. Suppose that you have `div` on every page and that `div` has `id="root"`, you can do this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Remember that you must include React's bundle `.js` file on every `html` page

Actually, I don't think it's a good practice when using React.

Comment: I followed your advice but was still not able to render the navigation bar in login.html. This is the login.html file                                                          <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>a</title>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>